# What is the X called in the "X:Y" identifier?

Tags: single-word-requests

An example from the info section of a book:

```
Year   : 1981
Author : Jean Baudrillard
Subject: Postmodern Philosophy
```

In general, it has the form *X*:*Y*.

What is the left side (*X*) of the colon (Year, Author, Subject, etc.) called in general?

Comment: There is no word for "the left side of a colon". For one thing, there are no colons in English, only in spelling, and spoken English is the source of words. For another, there is nothing in common to the "left side": it can be anything at all.

Comment: @Justin I land on the "needs more context" side as well. If we were talking about configuration files, for example, the left side of the colon would be a key. But that's not especially general.

Comment: @rojen There are lots of ways to refer to that label depending on context. There's key, label, feature, variable, dimension, scale, attribute, quality, aspect, field. The right hand side is usually called the value. If this wee a database it'd be the column name.

Comment: As usual I'm not sure why this is getting such negative feedback and close votes. This is a very legitimate question.

Comment: Questions about **the naming of *software elements* are off-topic for our site** according to [our help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "But please, don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site. ... Naming, including naming programming variables/classes".

Comment: @tchrist The OP doesn't say that he's asking in the context of computer software. His example says "the info section of a book", not "a JSON file".

Comment: Is the use of colons in this example essential to the question, or are you really asking something like: on a form, what is the term for the parts other than the filled-in content?

Comment: X:Y is not a form in English. It is just an expression.

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any general, widely accepted term for this.

If I had to suggest a general word I'd say "label" or possibly "caption". But others might have different suggestions. And the words "label" and "caption" are also used in other contexts.